# "Customize this page" option in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, modern-pages

I wonder if the option "Personalize this Page" which can be found in SharePoint Server 2016 (and lower I believe) to customize Web parts on the landing page does also exist out of the box in SharePoint Online (MS 365).

I couldn't find any article from Microsoft for this topic. I'm grateful for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Personalize this Page" option doesn’t exist in modern pages of SharePoint Online, we could find it in classic web part pages.

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks! Do you have any official Link for this provided by Microsoft?

Comment: From my search, I couldn't find official link about "Personalize this Page" option in SharePoint Online. I see the article about this option in SharePoint 2013:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31454.sharepoint-2013-personalize-a-page-and-configure-web-parts-to-create-a-personal-view.aspx